# How to run SBM algorithm in graph-tool package in parallel mode with OpenMP?

Tags: python, openmp, graph-tool

I've been using the [SBM algorithm](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/demos/inference/inference.html), implemented in the [graph-tool package](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/). I need to process a huge amount of data and need to run it in parallel.

I know that OpenMP is activated by default in this package and used in the specific and compatible algorithms, but the documentation doesn't specify which algorithms.

I've tried `openmp_enabled()` or `openmp_set_num_threads()` and also `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=16`. Everything seems fine but when I check the running processes, it's not paralleled.

Do you have any experience with implementing SBM parallelized?

Answer (score 2):

Although graph-tool uses OpenMP, not every algorithm is implemented in parallel, simply because this cannot be done in some cases. The SBM inference algorithm implemented in graph-tool is based on MCMC, which cannot be parallelized in general. Because of this, enabling OpenMP will have no effect.

Comment: Thank you, dear Tiago. It would be amazing if there was a shortlist of available algorithms that can be parallelized in graph-tools.

Comment: @Tiago, I'm confused.  Isn't the `(multiflip_)mcmc_sweep()` function parallelized via OpenMP? When I've used `minimize_blockmodel_dl()` in the past, I notice my CPU cores oscillating between full utilization (all cores) to single-core while the function runs, indicating that at least some of the computation is parallelized.  Wasn't that due to [this line](https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/-/blob/15a33b72ca2cc440885cf145fb888c7f205862ed/src/graph/inference/blockmodel/graph_blockmodel_multiflip_mcmc.cc#L110)?

Comment: @StuartBerg That line has to do with the *parallel tempering* algorithm (which runs in parallel), not the regular MCMC code (which does not)! The function minimize_blockmodel_dl() also has a block merging phase which *does* run in parallel, but that is a minor part.

Comment: @SaeedChoobani For all functions in graph-tool (singular) that are implemented in parallel, this is mentioned in the documentation. If this is not mentioned, then it's not the case.